# What are the available Spatial extensions API between Java and MySQL? [JTS Alternatives]

Tags: java, mysql, api, dictionary, geospatial

I'm planning to work with google maps api, to handle data I'm using MySQl and EclipseLink but I couldn't find (Spatial Geometry, point types in Java ) So I googled and found [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html), what are the available alternatives ? pros and cons would be appreciated if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JTS is a java library for working with Spatial data once you load it up into JTS objects. I would say you should just do the SQL calls in MySQL and then have it give you back JSON or XML for the geometries you need to work with.

I am not as familiar with MySQL but in PostGIS/Postgresql - there is a JDBC driver that supports spatial types and queries.

In either case - if you are already storing your data as spatial data then I would recommend using the SQL Engine to do your spatial operations rather than JTS.